# query data in ngResource (angularjs) based on selected item

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angularjs

I'm working on a small application where i would like to render a list of cities only when country is selected using ngResource in angularjs. Right now i can render the list of countries and cities which makes my system get slower and freezes my application at times (mostly in ios/Safari/iphone/ipad). I was able to create the filter in html, but my issue is that the list of cities gets downloaded first when i first open my application then it gets filtered. I want to be able to prevent the ngResource from rendering the list of cities until a specific country is selected. Below is my code and i hope someone has an answer to this, since i've had so many users complaining that their mobile phone and ipad is freezing when downloading my application.

Thanks in advance.

services.js:

```
.factory('Country', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/location/countries:id/');
}])

.factory('City', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/location/cities:id/');
}])
```

controllers.js:

```
$scope.countries = [];
  Country.query(function(response){
    $scope.countries = response;
  });



$scope.cities = [];
  City.query(function(response){
    $scope.cities = response;
  });
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label ng-model="country" class="formlabel col-sm-4 control-label">Country</label>        
<div class="col-sm-8 formbox" ng-model="country">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="country" ng-change="user.country=country" ng-options="country.country for country in countries track by country.id" id="country" name="userRegisterCountry" required>
<option value="">-- Choose Country --</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label ng-model="city" class="formlabel col-sm-4 control-label">City</label>
<div class="col-sm-8 formbox" ng-model="city">
<select class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-change="user.city=city" ng-options="city.city for city in cities | filter: {country:country.id} track by city.id" id="city" name="userRegisterCity" required>
<option value="">-- Choose City --</option>
</select> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the lag comes from populating + filtering a huge select list of cities. Are you able to fetch a subset of the cities when a country is selected, and not fetch any cities until then? You could let the city selection be disabled normally, and when a country is chose, fetch the cities in that country, and display ONLY those cities in the city dropdown, without filters, even.

Try something like the following:

JS:

```
$scope.selectCountry = function() {
  $scope.user.country = $scope.country
  MyApi.fetchCities($scope.country.id) // just an example, replace with something suitable for your case
  .then(function(cities) {
    $scope.country.cities = cities;
  })
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label ng-model="country" class="formlabel col-sm-4 control-label">Country</label>        
    <div class="col-sm-8 formbox" ng-model="country">
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="country" ng-change="selectCountry()" ng-options="country.country for country in countries track by country.id" id="country" name="userRegisterCountry" required>
            <option value="">-- Choose Country --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label ng-model="city" class="formlabel col-sm-4 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8 formbox" ng-model="city">
        <select ng-disabled="!country" class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-change="user.city=city" ng-options="city.city for city in country.cities" id="city" name="userRegisterCity" required>
            <option value="">-- Choose City --</option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

This way you'd only have a limited amount of cities to populate the dropdown with, which should cause less lag. In addition, we get rid of filtering the huge city list, which further helps.

EDIT: Option 2 if your API can't filter cities by country - HTML stays mostly the same:

```
$scope.countries = [];
Country.query(function(response) {
    $scope.countries = response;
    City.query(function(cities) {
        _.forEach(cities, function(city) {
            var country = _.find($scope.countries, {id: city.country});
            country.cities = country.cities || [];
            country.cities.push(city);
        })
    });
});
```

In this case, too, the dropdown will never be populated with the whole list of cities which should reduce lag.

Comment: Fissio thanks for your quick reply, i tried your solution but i didn't understand where FetchCities is coming from? for MyAPI, i did $http.get call to my api to fecth all cities but i guess that is the problem i was trying to avoid in the first place. any suggestions would be appreciated. Are you able to fetch a subset of the cities when a country is selected, and not fetch any cities until then? this is exactly wht iwas trying to achieve but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Hamid If your API can't provide you a smaller set of cities, you can try to divide the cities country by country when you first fetch them, to avoid overpopulating the select... I'll update my answer in a few minutes

Comment: @Hamid Added another solution - you may need to tweak it a bit but go with the idea that you should never try to have all cities in the dropdown at the same time

Comment: Fissio, i tried your first code, made some tweaks to make it suitable to my api, my code is as follows: $scope.selectCountry = function(country) {
  $scope.user.country = $scope.country
    City.query({country: country.id}).$promise.then(function(cities) {
      $scope.country.cities = cities;
    }) 
  }    however i get two errors, first error that cities is undefined, and the list of cities is not filtered i get all cities rendered. Am i doing anything wrong here. Thanks again

Comment: parameters are passed like this to render cities: /api/location/cities/?country=1" .